Regex Substitue only on a specific group - sedcmd (Splunk)
[so much data exists in the same single line ] ,"Comments": "New alert", **"Data": "{\"etype\":\"MalwareFamily\",\"at\":\"2024-06-21T11:34:07.0000000Z\",\"md\":\"2024-06-21T11:34:07.0000000Z\",\"Investigations\":[{\"$id\":\"1\",\"Id\":\"urn:ZappedUrlInvestigation:2cc87ae3\",\"InvestigationStatus\":\"Running\"}],\"InvestigationIds\":[\"urn:ZappedUrlInvestigation:2cc8782d063\"],\"Intent\":\"Probing\",\"ResourceIdentifiers\":[{\"$id\":\"2\",\"AadTenantId\":\"2dfb29-729c918\",\"Type\":\"AAD\"}],\"AzureResourceId\":null,\"WorkspaceId\":null,\"Metadata\":{\"CustomApps\":null,\"GenericInfo\":null},\"Entities\":[{\"$id\":\"3\",\"MailboxPrimaryAddress\":\"abc@gmail.com\",\"Upn\":\"abc@gmail.com\",\"AadId\":\"6eac3b76357\",\"RiskLevel\":\"None\",\"Type\":\"mailbox\",\"Urn\":\"urn:UserEntity:10338af2b6c\",\"Source\":\"TP\",\"FirstSeen\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\"}, \"StartTimeUtc\": \"2024-06-21T10:12:37\", \"Status\": \"Investigation Started\"}",** "EntityType": "MalwareFamily", [so much data exists in the same single line ]
In a single line, there exists so much data,

I want to substitue(\") with (") only that falls between Data dictionary value, nothing before and nothing after. sample regex : https://regex101.com/r/Gsfaay/1 ( highlighted data only in group 4 should be modified.)
And the Dictionary value is enclosed between quotes(as string) want it to be replaced by []braces as list ( group 3 and 6 )

eg : [so much data exists in the same single line ],"Comments": "New alert", "Data": [{"etype":"MalwareFamily", so on,"Status":"Investigation Started"}],"EntityType": "MalwareFamily", [so much data exists in the same single line ]```


This looks like JSON. You should use a tool that parses it, like jq, rather than a text tool.

It's definitely outside the limited capabilities of sed. You need a language that allows you to extract the substring between dictionary values, perform a substitution within that, then replaces the original string with that.

I cannot use a pythonscript , i need it to be implemented in Splunk, so the only option I have is sedcmd.
I tried the below, but first one i am applying globally to the entire event but I should apply only to the values that fall betwen Data dictionary value.
SEDCMD-DataJson = s/\"/"/g s/"Data": "{"/"Data": [{"/g s/("Data": [{".*})",/$1],/g

In Splunk , sedcmd works on _raw. There is no option to apply it on a specific field.
Temporary solution : When a Field value is passed as string format instead of list in a json file
Search Time extraction :
| rex mode=sed "s/(\"Data\":\s+)\"/\1[/g s/(\"Data\":\s+\[{.*})\"/\1]/g s/\\\\\"/\"/g" 
| extract pairdelim="\"{,}" kvdelim=":"

Index Time extraction :
SEDCMD-o365DataJsonRemoveBackSlash = s/(\\)+"/"/g s/(\"Data\":\s+)\"/\1[/g s/(\"Data\":\s+\[{.*})\"/\1]/g


You can use (?:"Data":\s*")(.*?)(?<!\\)" with replace():
import re

s = """
[so much data exists in the same single line ] ,"Comments": "New alert", "Data": "{\"etype\":\"MalwareFamily\",\"at\":\"2024-06-21T11:34:07.0000000Z\",\"md\":\"2024-06-21T11:34:07.0000000Z\",\"Investigations\":[{\"$id\":\"1\",\"Id\":\"urn:ZappedUrlInvestigation:2cc87ae3\",\"InvestigationStatus\":\"Running\"}],\"InvestigationIds\":[\"urn:ZappedUrlInvestigation:2cc8782d063\"],\"Intent\":\"Probing\",\"ResourceIdentifiers\":[{\"$id\":\"2\",\"AadTenantId\":\"2dfb29-729c918\",\"Type\":\"AAD\"}],\"AzureResourceId\":null,\"WorkspaceId\":null,\"Metadata\":{\"CustomApps\":null,\"GenericInfo\":null},\"Entities\":[{\"$id\":\"3\",\"MailboxPrimaryAddress\":\"abc@gmail.com\",\"Upn\":\"abc@gmail.com\",\"AadId\":\"6eac3b76357\",\"RiskLevel\":\"None\",\"Type\":\"mailbox\",\"Urn\":\"urn:UserEntity:10338af2b6c\",\"Source\":\"TP\",\"FirstSeen\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\"}, \"StartTimeUtc\": \"2024-06-21T10:12:37\", \"Status\": \"Investigation Started\"}", "EntityType": "MalwareFamily", [so much data exists in the same single line ]
"""

matches = re.compile(r'(?:"Data":\s*")(.*?)(?<!\\)"').findall(s)

if matches:
    for m in matches:
        R = m.replace('\\"', '"')
        s = s.replace(m, R)

print(s)


Prints

[so much data exists in the same single line ] ,"Comments": "New alert", "Data": "{"etype":"MalwareFamily","at":"2024-06-21T11:34:07.0000000Z","md":"2024-06-21T11:34:07.0000000Z","Investigations":[{"$id":"1","Id":"urn:ZappedUrlInvestigation:2cc87ae3","InvestigationStatus":"Running"}],"InvestigationIds":["urn:ZappedUrlInvestigation:2cc8782d063"],"Intent":"Probing","ResourceIdentifiers":[{"$id":"2","AadTenantId":"2dfb29-729c918","Type":"AAD"}],"AzureResourceId":null,"WorkspaceId":null,"Metadata":{"CustomApps":null,"GenericInfo":null},"Entities":[{"$id":"3","MailboxPrimaryAddress":"abc@gmail.com","Upn":"abc@gmail.com","AadId":"6eac3b76357","RiskLevel":"None","Type":"mailbox","Urn":"urn:UserEntity:10338af2b6c","Source":"TP","FirstSeen":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"}, "StartTimeUtc": "2024-06-21T10:12:37", "Status": "Investigation Started"}", "EntityType": "MalwareFamily", [so much data exists in the same single line ]


Note:

You can include more limitations to your pattern, such as with:

(?:"Data":\s*")(.*?)(?<!\\)}"\s*,\s*"


Splunk:

You can do it in multiple steps in Splunk:

| rex field=_raw "(?:\"Data\":\s*\")(?<extract>.*?)(?<!\\)}\"\s*,\s*\""

| eval rm = replace(extract, "\\\"", "\"")


Ref


I cannot use a pythonscript , i need it to be implemented in Splunk, so the only option I have is sedcmd. I tried the below, but first one i am applying globally to the entire event but I should apply only to the values that fall betwen Data dictionary value. SEDCMD-DataJson = s/\"/"/g s/"Data": "{"/"Data": [{"/g s/("Data": [{".*})",/$1],/g

@NagasriVarma How about 2 steps: (?:"Data":\s*")(.*?)(?<!\\)" and get the value, then (?:\\)(?=") replace it with an empty string ""?

There might be spaces in between , replacing with empty space, will not break the event properly in Splunk. (eg :  "Malware Family") should be considered as a single entitty.

"There might be spaces in between" where? @NagasriVarma Do you mean in between "\" and "? In that case, you can try (?:\\\s*)(?=")? Wherever there was an optional space situation, you can simply add a \s*.

I tried it in the multiple steps as mentioned in my first comment example, but In splunk sedcmd works on the entire event always ( i.e on s value). I shouldnt apply it globally

https://regex101.com/r/0g2bcL/1
https://regex101.com/r/o3eFgJ/1
https://regex101.com/r/D7Of0v/1

only issue with the first one, it shouldnt be applied globally on entire "s" value, it should be applying only between data dictionary value.

@NagasriVarma Updated. You should be able to do multiple steps operations in Splunk.

@NagasriVarma Added Splunk tag. Someone might help you out.
